# How to force developer tools to open in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, developer-tools

I need to force open the developer tab in IE. I'm working with an application in IE that has "disabled shortcuts". I would like to open the developer tab to modify the client side layout for better work flow. Is there a way to force open the developer tab to add my custom JavaScript to improve work flow?

**EDIT** The application is in a window without any tool bars or access to anything but the url. IE is required. No other browser will support the application without crashing

Comment: Not with JavaScript.

Comment: shift + f12 should do it

Comment: Can't you do it from a menu rather than a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: This is not possible for obvious security reasons.

Comment: I should have clarified and will edit my question. I'm in a window without any tool bars or access to anything but the url

Comment: Can you copy-paste the URL into a new window?

Comment: Can not the application will log you out.

Comment: Do you need to use IE to do this? I assume the right-click menu is disabled? You could analyze how it opens the window, and probably do some trickery.

Comment: IE is required. No other browser will support the application without crashing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. If you click on the URL and then press F12 you can access the developer tools.

Comment: This is great to know...  I've run across many an application that blocks the F12 keypress (opening dev tools).   This solution, clicking on the URL first, seems to solve the problem with all of them.    Thanks!